# Display Percentage Values on (highcharts) bubble chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/ewng3aqa/

I have bubble size value. i want to show the value with percentage how to show the value with percentage.Its Possible to shows or not? 
 Display Percentage Values on bubble chart

```
   Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'bubble',
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    zoomType: 'xy'
},

title: {
    text: 'Highcharts bubbles with radial gradient fill'
},

xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1
},

yAxis: {
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false
},
plotOptions: {
    bubble: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            x:30
        },
    }
},
series: [{
    data: [
        [9, 81, 63],
        [98, 5, 89],
        [51, 50, 73],
        [41, 22, 14],
        [58, 24, 20],
        [78, 37, 34],
        [55, 56, 53],
        [18, 45, 70],
        [42, 44, 28],
        [3, 52, 59],
        [31, 18, 97],
        [79, 91, 63],
        [93, 23, 23],
        [44, 83, 22]
    ],
    marker: {
        fillColor: {
            radialGradient: { cx: 0.4, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.5).get('rgba')]
            ]
        }
    }
}, ]

});
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you'll have to be more specific about what you want. Which value is the percent value that you want to show? Look at the `format` property of the `dataLabels`, or the `formatter` function of the `dataLabels`. Ref:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cbubble%3E.dataLabels.format | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cbubble%3E.dataLabels.formatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add the format option

```
 bubble: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                x:30,
                format: "{y}%"
            },
        }
```

see fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ewng3aqa/1/

Comment: you can use  format: "{point.z}%" as a format, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cscp8yef/3/

Answer (score -2):

See other answers for simpler solution. For the more complex solution using jquery:

The setTimeout is used to wait for the Chart to be loaded.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var objects = $('.highcharts-data-label text tspan');
    var text = "";
    objects.each(function(){
        text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text + ' %');
    });
},500);
```