# Display Percentage Values on Z-axis (highcharts) bubble chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[I want to show the displaying in percentage in z-axis](https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/cscp8yef/)

```
plotOptions: {
  bubble: {
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        x:30
    }
  }
}
```

I want my tada labels to be values of z axis with a % sign next to it. So if I have a data point `[1, 10, 5]`, I would like the data label to be `5%`.

Comment: What data points do you have? Maybe simple numbers with a `%` label will do the job for you?

Comment: see above the link i had added

Comment: Still not sure what you are trying to do? Where do you want the % labels to appear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Percentage Values on (highcharts) bubble chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533334/display-percentage-values-on-highcharts-bubble-chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to display z value of data as percentage

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/s1xk3p4j/)

```
plotOptions: {
    bubble: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            x:30,
            format: "{point.z}%"
        },
    }
},
```